# Video downloader not downloading file in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, video, actionscript

I have created Video downloader AIR application. 
Which will download remote file to locally.

I write following code to download file.

```
var urlString:String = REMOTE_URL;
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlString);

urlStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
urlStream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, writeFile);
urlStream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIoError);

var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("D:/test.mp4");
fileStream.openAsync(file, FileMode.WRITE);

urlStream.load(urlReq);

function writeFile(event:ProgressEvent):void 
{
    if (urlStream.bytesAvailable > 51200) 
    {
          progBar.setProgress(event.bytesLoaded,event.bytesTotal);
          var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
          urlStream.readBytes(data, 0, urlStream.bytesAvailable);
          fileStream.writeBytes(data, 0, data.length);
    }
}

function onIoError(event:IOErrorEvent):void
{
        trace("IO Error");
}

function loaded(event:Event):void {}
```

It will download some file successfully. But from some url it will not download file. It will return `event.bytesTotal = 162 bytes` only. even it will available more than 200 MB.

When i check it's `content-type` using `HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS` listener then it's give `text/html; charset=utf-8`

I open that URL in browser and try to save then it will successfully download it.

Hope some one has solution for it.
Thanks.

Comment: Try to read these 162 bytes. Maybe it's an HTML code.

Comment: How i can read that?

Comment: `readUTFBytes`. Send me URL and I'll try to read these 162 bytes.

Comment: Thanks and Sorry, but i can't give you url for security purpose. it will not allow me to share url where i work.

Comment: But i ask my friend he says same like you. Is there any solution for that to access that URL to download video from that in flex.

Comment: I don't know. Try to use `readUTFBytes` or HTTP sniffer to see what's downloaded instead of video. Maybe it's security error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72670/discussion-between-ketan-and-subdan).

Comment: Ok. I've written to a chat.

Comment: @subdan sorry for late reply. It will not go in completeHandler. It will got to i/o error.

Comment: @subdan In i/o error gives error: `Error #2032: Stream Error. URL`

Comment: But after adding `HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS` event handler i got 0 bytes available ( `trace(ba.bytesAvailable);` )  in complete handler.

Comment: And i get content-type of that file in event then value of it is. `"text/html; charset=utf-8"`.

Comment: I've tried to go to your url address and got “Wrong IP”.

Comment: @subdan have you check this? `http://185.45.15.117/kj2vyxizei6vtaw52boj4264nxgo7dsynuzdiwu32fdizhjb4tls2ehw76da/v.mp4`

Comment: @subdan Don't know why this thing happen. when i copy that link here and open it gives error.

Comment: @subdan But, as you say above it gives "content-type" = "text/html".

Comment: This link doesn't work: “Not Found”.

Comment: @subdan Ok. i think some issue with that url. anyway is there any way to get video from `content-type  = text/html` ?

Comment: I don't know. Sorry.